# order of priority_queue not expected

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have the following definitions:

```
struct vertex {
int number;
bool mixed = false;

vertex(int n):number(n){};

bool operator > (const vertex & v)const{
    return d[this->number] > d[v.number];
}
```

with

```
priority_queue<vertex, vector<vertex>, greater<vertex> >q
```

after my debugging, I found the queue not sorted as I expected ( following the order of array *d* ). I wonder why. During the process array *d* is modified serveral times.

Comment: Are you modifying values in `d` after pushing elements into the `priority_queue`?

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, but it is my intention for identifying different vertices

Comment: The `priority_queue` is a heap with the elements ordered by the comparison you provided. If you change the vertex values after-the-fact the heap doesn't get magically reordered. You are trashing the data structure invariants. You need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, if `x` is already stored in `priority_queue` and you modify `d[x]`, you will destroy your data structure.
An obvious solution is to remove element, change `d` and then place it back.
AFAIK, `priority_queue` doesn't allow random-access removals, so you can use `set`. `set.begin()` returns the lowest element.

```
void update(int x, int v) {
  set.erase(x);
  d[x] = v;
  set.insert(x);
}

int getMin() {
  return *set.begin();
}
```

Comment: so did you mean the heap changes only after an insertion or removal ? but my debugger tells me the heap really changes (from the sequence of elements in the queue) even if i never applied erase() or insert(). Actually apple clang and microsoft vc++ behaved differently on the sequence after my test.

Comment: No, I didn't mention this. Heap doesn't change: elements are located in the same way as before. But you destroy relations between them, and who knows what will happen. Heap relies on few properties of comparison, such as transitivity and others. You violate one of them, namely that comparison of two given elements always returns the same result. In such case heap doesn't promise you anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `d` as part of the ordering for your `priority_queue`, you can't make changes to it once you start adding things to the queue.  Doing so would potentially change the ordering of the objects contained in the queue, and would break the *strict weak ordering* required of the comparison used for a `priority_queue`.

In addition, the elements within a [`priorty_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)  are not completely sorted, because it is implemented using a [heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap).

Comment: d is modified as a characteristic to distinguish different vertices. if d keeps untouched all the time, wouldn't all elements in the queue be the same?

Comment: @brightyang It depends on what the change is.  If you _ever_ make a change to `d` that would change the result of a _single_ comparison, the ordering is broken.  If this is something you need to do, then perhaps using the heap functions directly - where you can rebuild/reorder the heap - may work better.